# Generate random number, the same every time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random, ruby-2.3

I have collections of items (ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation).

I need to randomly pick one item from each collection, but it should pick the same item the second and third time etc.

I'm thinking of some kind of one way algorithm, like hashing. E.g. perhaps based on the length of the collection, let's say 50, it will always generate the number 34.

Any idea how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Couldn't you just store the index # from your random number generator? IE, generate a random number, store it, and reuse it for each collection? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I could, but it isn't that important worth storing in DB.

Comment: Seemingly related  http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/random_number.png

Comment: Well, if you needed to you could seed the RNG with the length of your collection. That way it'll consistently get the same number as long as it gets a collection of the same size (though the collections you're picking from need to be the same size)

Comment: Please any example?

Comment: I'm less familiar with Ruby, but on [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Random.html) page they have some info on how to generate random numbers as well as with how to seed them. Just make a Random object and use your collection size as the seed.

Comment: ``Random.new(collection.size).rand(collection.size)``

Answer (score 4):

The Array `sample`method takes a Random Number Generator as a (named) argument, so you can do:

```
rng = Random.new(8) # The seed (8) is just a meaningles number.
a = ("a".."z").to_a
p a.sample(random: rng) # "d"
p a.sample(random: rng) # "u"
```

The next time it will result in "d" and "u" again.

If a repeatable random sequence is needed, all you need is a seeded Random number generator

```
rng2 = Random.new(10)
num = rng2.rand(collection.size)
```

Comment: This would be fine if OP had an array, but OP has an ActiveRecord::Relation. This solution would fetch all of the records in the relation in order to get a single one at random. That's less than optimal, to say the least.

Comment: @Jordan I don't do Rails, I mistakenly tough this collection would be an array already. Editting...

Comment: @Jordan You can always fetch all IDs, then randomly select one of those: `pluck(:id)` usually returns manageable amounts of data.